# Easiest way to access SOAP web service if I've SOAP envelope ready?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I've a complete SOAP envelope (XML) ready. What would be the easiest way to send this envelope in php? I know about SoapClient and Zend_Soap_Client but please consider this particular case, where I just want to send this envelope and print the xml response.

```
//Pseudo function for what I wanna do
public function sendEnvelope($xmlEnvelope, $url)
{
  //send this envelope to $url
  //return response
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got the Zend Framework to hand you could perhaps do something like:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setUri($url);
$client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
$client->setRawData($xmlEnvelope, 'application/soap+xml');
$response = $client->request();
```

Alternatively you can use cURL with a good introduction available at 
[Techniques for Mastering cURL](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/techniques-and-resources-for-mastering-curl/) from Nettus+